# which jar file is used if we put different version of same jar, one in tomcat lib and another in project lib directory in Grails?

Tags: tomcat, grails

I have a grails application, if i put different version of same jar file in tomcat lib and Project lib directory which one is loaded when we create a war file and deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever is in the WARs `WEB-INF/lib` directory will override what is present in the Tomcat `lib` directory.